# How do I update multiple rows using an array in mysql using node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, loops

I'm trying to use UPDATE to update 3 different columns in my table(stores).  I would like to add a openingTime, closingTime, and phoneNumber...but I want them added via an storeId, which already exists in the table.  Do I need to make an individual call for each entry based on storeId.  Or is it possible for me to make a single call to the table and loop through each storeId?

Here's what I have so far.

```
var arraythatcontainsEverything = [];

var locations = ["randomA", "randomB", "randomC", ];
var openingTime = ["10:00", "10:00", "10:00"];
var closingTime = ["24:00", "24:00", "24:00"];
var phoneNumber = ["123-4567", "123-6789", "123-9999"];
var ids = ["210", "213", "234"];


var q = 'UPDATE stores SET openingTime=?, closingHours=?, phoneNumber=?  WHERE StoreId=?';
con.query(q, [array that contains everything], function(err, results){
if(err) console.log(err); 
if (DEBUG >= 2 )console.log("finished inserting hours and phone number into database");
                con.end();
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Support for multiple statements is disabled for security reasons (it
>   allows for SQL injection attacks if values are not properly escaped).
>   To use this feature you have to enable it for your connection:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

[Here is the MySQLJS Multiple Statement Queries Documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries)

Once enabled, you would have to build a (multiple statement) query string.

Its really easy, if you are going to loop to build each independent query and append it to the final query string, I would suggest using underscore's each.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Sorry about the delayed response!

Comment: @VincentKuneen Have you tried it ? has this question been solved ? :)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mark it as being solved.  I was able to get it to work.  Thanks again!